Render to texture with FBO not working when running a shader to process the render source
I am trying to render a texture which is an FBO attachment, to another FBO attachment and processing it with a shader while doing so. What is working is to render to an FBO attachment and then use the attachment as regular texture and render it on the screen. Things go sideways when I activate the shader. I have written shaders and RTT using FBOs before, but I cannot get this one to work, and I am clueless of what I may be overlooking.
The FBO and its attachments seem to be setup correctly, so I won't post that code here for the sake of keeping this short.
Here's a very simplified shader just setting the fragment color:
// vertex shader
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
uniform mat4 mModelView;
uniform mat4 mProjection;
out vec2 fragCoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = mProjection * mModelView * vec4 (position, 1.0);
    fragCoord = texCoord;
} 

//fragment shader
#version 330
in vec2 fragCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;
uniform sampler2D source;
void main() {
    fragColor = vec4(fragCoord.y, fragCoord.x, 0.0, 1.0);
}

Here's the rendering code after setting the draw buffer and binding the source texture (I tried to make it super simple to be error proof):
glBegin (GL_QUADS)
glTexCoord2f (0,0)
glVertex2f (0,0)
glTexCoord2f (0,1)
glVertex2f (0,1)
glTexCoord2f (1,1)
glVertex2f (1,1)
glTexCoord2f (1,0)
glVertex2f (1,0)
glEnd()

The effect in the fragment shader is that fragCoord.x is always 1 and fragCoord.y is always 0. So the shader is running and returning a color, and the entire area covered by the source texture gets colored accordingly. But I can't access the texture properly. However, just rendering to that texture while using it as the FBO's color attachment  and then rendering it to the screen works fine.
Probably a very stupid mistake I made, but after hours of inspecting my code and doing tests I don't seem to be able to figure it.
